# Aligning text boxes

Tags: windows, delphi, themes, c++builder

I'm have some [data output text boxes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa511494.aspx#dataOutput) (text boxes with no border and with the same background as the rest of the window) that I'm trying to align with a standard edit control + spin button, to represent a column of numbers, one of which can be edited:

[image: screen shot]

I can manually align these in the Delphi / C++Builder form designer, but when I then view the form on a different version of Windows or at a different DPI, the text is no longer right-justified, presumably because of differences in the spin button spacing, borders, etc.

I can use EM_GETMARGINS to determine the width of the spin button, but how can I determine the size of the edit control's margins and borders?  I've tried various combinations of EM_POSFROMCHAR, ClientToScreen, GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXBORDER), GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXEDGE), and GetThemeMargins, but so far, I can't find a combination that works and makes sense.

More details:

- Environment is Delphi / C++Builder XE2.
- The data output controls are TEdits with BorderStyle bsNone.
- The edit + spin button is a TJvSpinEdit.  From viewing its source, it uses EM_SETMARGINS to allow space for its spin button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Win32 API `GetWindowRect()` and `GetClientRect()` methods.  The bordering will be the difference between the two rectangles.  That will only give you the bordering, though.  There could be extra spacing inside the client area.

Comment: I had tried this earlier, but it didn't work.  Apparently it fails when done from the TFrame's constructor but works when done as the form is being shown.  There is still a 1 pixel discrepancy; it looks like it might be from TJvSpinEdit's implementation, although I can't see anything that might cause it.

Comment: Then try using the `EM_GETRECT` message instead.  It returns the bounding rectangle that the Edit control can render its text in. If that works, then you can position the controls so their right-hand rectangle edges line up.

Comment: If you have the VCL source code installed, you can alternatively have a look at the implementation of the following classes, which is what the Form Designer uses to calculate various alignments when the "Designer Guidelines" feature is enabled: `DesignIntf.TBaseComponentGuidelines`, 
`DesignEditors.TComponentGuidelines`, `VCLEditors.TControlGuidelines`, and `VCLEditors.TControlGuidelines`.

Comment: I'm still unable to figure out the 1 pixel discrepancy, but I'm going to assume it's some quirk of TJvSpinEdit that I haven't tracked down.  Everything else is working now; thank you.